# Interchanging map and filter positions in streams

Tags: java

I interchanged the positions of map and filter. Does it make any difference related to number of iterations done by code ?

```
 List<String> Aname3 =names.stream()
     .map(name->name.toUpperCase())
     .filter(name->name.startsWith("A"))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());

 List<String> Aname4 =names.stream()
     .filter(name->!name.startsWith("A"))
     .map(name->name.toLowerCase())
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `name->!name.startsWith("A")` and `name->name.startsWith("A")` have opposite meaning. Same goes for `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase`

Comment: The above 2 logics were for different functionalities. It was just to show what was done. The real concern was how the performance would change if position of maps and filter were interchanged for same functionality.

Comment: Generally, when you switch `map` and `filter` the code does not return the same result. Any performance comparison of two blocks of code that do different things would be meaningless.

Comment: Take for example just the first block of code with map first and then filter applied. Now rewriting with filter first and then map would produce same result of names that starts with "A" and will be uppercased. So now this code will be doing exactly what the first block is doing. I am trying to ask for performance comparison of these 2 .

Comment: It wouldn't produce the same result, that's the point! Think of the input stream of 1000 strings starting in lowercase `"a"`. If `map` to upper goes first, you get back 1000 results. If `filter` on starts with uppercase `"A"` goes first, you get back zero results.

Comment: Exactly, just Think of the input stream of 1000 strings starting in Uppercase "A". If map to upper goes first, you get back 1000 results. If filter on starts with "A" goes first, you again get back 1000 results.They produce the same result But are their performance same.

Comment: In this case `filter` does nothing, so it does not matter if it goes first or last. In fact, you can remove it altogether, and have the same performance as before.

Comment: You give 500 strings with names starting with uppercase "A" and 50 with uppercase "B". First map and then filter will give 500 uppercased strings starting with "A". Now first filter and then map will again give 500 uppercased strings starting with "A". That means both filtered out the rest 50. But does their performance differ. This is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Now your input is such that `filter` and `map` are independent of each other. That's a pretty narrow case, but if you want an answer, you should be able to figure it out by counting how many `toUpperCase` and `startsWith` calls would be performed in both arrangements of `filter` and `map`.

Comment: So in one case filter would narrow down the calls to be sent to map to work upon. And in another map would sent all strings to filter to work upon. So in one case filter is operating on all strings sent and in other map is operating on all the strings sent. So which performs the bulk of the task faster map or filter

Comment: If map goes first, filter gets 550 uppercased strings, of which 500 are kept. If filter goes first, it gets 550 non-uppercased strings, of which only 500 are then uppercased by map - a saving of 50 calls to `toUpperCase`.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering may filer out some elements so mapping to upper case will be done on fewer elements. So, yes. It is better to filter first.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these two stream pipelines have different logic that will produce different outputs. Even if both `filter` and `map` calls received the same functional interfaces as input, the outcome of the two pipelines may still be different, since `map` changes the elements of the `Stream` in a manner that may affect the outcome of `filter`, so the order of `map` and `filter` affects the output.

As for the number of iterations, applying the `filter` first means that `map` would only be applied to elements that pass the filter.

On the other hand, applying `map` first means that it will be applied to all the elements in the `Stream`.

Therefore the second stream pipeline will perform less operations (assuming not all the elements pass the filter).